# How to use vlookup in excel for a faster outcome. Need better alternatives than xlookup

Tags: excel

Not able to search across columns

Solution or alternatives. Trued out x lookup; index search but in general they are complicated to use. Are there any easier alternatives and which are faster on larger datasets.

Primary purpose is for excels with more 700k rows.

Comment: `INDEX()/MATCH()` could be a good alternative.

Comment: Are you using `XLOOKUP` binary search mode? or `VLOOKUP` range lookup = TRUE? Both should vastly improve the speed for that many rows. Same with `MATCH` match type = less than or greater than.